# C# generic error in GDI+ when saving an image

Tags: c#, image, stream, bitmap, gdi+

When I try to save an image using either `System.Drawing.Image.Save(String)` or `System.Drawing.Bitmap.Save(String)` an exception is throw indicating a generic error in GDI+. Searching the web and Stack Overflow shows that I should be making sure I don't close the stream the image came from, but in my case the image was downloaded from the internet through a 3rd party library and I have no control over the stream it was read from (if it was even read from  a stream)

I've tried a few things such as copying the image, but I always get the same error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this in the past. Make sure you have write permissions to wherever you're saving the file.

Comment: Yep, this one's a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Save(String, ImageFormat) overload.  The image format inference doesn't appear to work particularly well.